# multiprocessing value hangs with lock

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I've read the documentation [here](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/04/shared-counter-with-pythons-multiprocessing), and seems that to make sure that the Value does not hang we need to use a lock. I did just that but it still gets stuck:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, freeze_support, Lock
nb_threads = 3
nbloops = 10
v = Value('i', 0)

def run_process(lock):
    global nbloops
    i = 0
    while i < nbloops:
        # do stuff
        i += 1
        with lock:
            v.value += 1
        # wait for all the processes to finish doing something
        while v.value % nb_threads != 0:
            pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    processes = []
    lock = Lock()

    for i in range(0, 3):
        processes.append( Process( target=run_process, args=(lock,) ) )
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

I've tried accessing the value using lock but it still blocks:

```
        val = -1
        while val % nb_threads != 0:
            with lock:
                val = v.value
```

How can I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has a race condition; you do not guarantee that all three processes break free from the `while v.value % nb_threads != 0` loop before allowing them to move on. This allows one or two of the processes to move on to the next iteration of the `while i < nbloops` loop, increment `v.value`, and then prevent the remaining process/processes from ever breaking out of their own `while v.value % nb_threads !=  0` loop. The kind of synchronization you're trying to do there is best handled by a [`Barrier`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Barrier), rather than looping and repeatedly checking the value.

Also, `multiprocessing.Value` also has a built-in synchronization by default, and you can explicitly access the `Lock` it uses for that by calling `Value.get_lock`, so there is no need to explicitly a `Lock` of your own to each process. Putting together, you have:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, freeze_support, Lock, Barrier
nb_threads = 3
nbloops = 10
v = Value('i', 0)

def run_process(barrier):
    global nbloops
    i = 0
    while i < nbloops:
        # do stuff
        i += 1
        with v.get_lock():
            v.value += 1
        # wait for all the processes to finish doing something
        out = barrier.wait()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    processes = []
    b = Barrier(nb_threads)

    for i in range(0, nb_threads):
        processes.append( Process( target=run_process, args=(b,) ) )
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

The `Barrier` guarantees that no process can move on to the next iteration of the loop until all of them have called `Barrier.wait()`, at which point all three are simultaneously able to progress. The `Barrier` object supports re-use, so it can safely be called on each iteration.